# Different ways of saying Aluminium

Tags: pronunciation, american-english, british-english

this is a very short question but me and a couple of friends have been discussing this for a little.

Does anyone know why Americans and British people especially insists on saying "Aloominum" and "Aloominium" respectively?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium#Etymology

Comment: There are [two](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/aluminium) different accepted pronunciations in BrE.

Comment: I don't think you've got they British pronunciation quite right - I'm in southern England, and the second syllable IME is pronouned the same as *you*, not the *oo* sound you use.

Comment: @Edwin: I think the only reason there are two BrE pronunciations is because some people enunciate the second vowel as a diphthong (the difference between *few* and *two*). But that difference is pretty trivial and normally wouldn't be noticed because in practice it's just an unstressed schwa anyway. The big difference is that Americans put stress on that second syllable, whereas *Brits stress the **third** syllable.*

Comment: Certainly – but it's good to correct the question before starting to answer it. Chris H also picks up on OP's claimed universal yod-dropping here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both forms derive from *alum* (and related, *alumina*) because aluminium is one of the elements in it, and was discovered by investigating *alum*, and *-ium* as an ending for elements (particularly the most earliest named as elements, like *helium*, and also metals).

Davy first called it *alumium*.

However, while he tended toward *-ium* endings when proposing element names (something he did quite a bit, potassium, sodium, magnesium, calcium, zirconium and strontium where all isolated by him, and he also proposed *silicium* and *glucium* as names which did not get used), there are also many elements that have names ending in *-um* but not *-ium*, such as platinum and molybdenum.

So later he changed the proposed name to *aluminum*.

Still, as *-ium* was the more common spelling for new metals, many people added an *i* into Davy's second proposal, producing *aluminium*. After Davy's original *alumium* was forgotten, both *aluminum* and *aluminium* were used, with the latter more common everywhere (including North America) because the *-ium* spelling was the more usual sort of spelling for such a word.

When Charles Martin Hall invented a much cheaper way of producing aluminium, he used the less usual *aluminum* spelling in an advertisement, despite the fact that he generally tended to use the *aluminium* spelling. This and subsequent advertisements by Hall, who was the main producer of the metal at the time, led to *aluminum* becoming the name that most non-chemists in North America new the metal by.

The impact was not as great on the rest of the world, so *aluminium* remained more common as the more usual style of name for a metal.

Comment: NP. The other thing Hall was responsible for was cheapening Piccadilly Circus. The Shaftesbury Memorial was made out of aluminium precisely because it was such an expensive metal (along with the lightness and strength that makes it still useful). While it was being made, Hall was taking his new method of producing it and turning it into and invention that would soon make aluminium a few hundred times cheaper than it had been, hence devaluing any large aluminium statues of Anteros that anyone might have erected in their cities in the meantime.

Comment: For the record, the American pronunciation is [ə'lumɨnɨm] and the RP is [æljʊ'mɪniəm]. I.e, the stress falls on the antepenult, no matter how many syllables it has, and this makes the difference in pronunciation much more distinct than the minuscule difference in spelling would suggest.

Comment: Unfortunately this question - a very good one - is closed, but this answer still sits here. But this answer doesn't note an essential fact: the *-ium* suffix was only being established as default around this time. Before that, the suffix was *-um* added to classical root word, with *-ium* occurring mostly where classical roots already ended with i. Molybdenum was named around the same time, but was based on a root without i. Tantalum, also from the same time without an 'i' in the root, developed a popular "tantalium" variant that died out. Only in later decades did -ium become default.

Comment: To be clear: I'm not arguing that aluminum or aluminium is "better" -- only that the reason there are two forms is because this word emerged right around the time practice in naming elements was shifting.

Comment: @Athanasius true, though it's interesting that Davy (after his first *alumium* that nobody uses any more) went for an *-um* spelling given his generally being one of those that leant towards *-ium*.